# Configure postfix/php send mail

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I work on a dedicated server OVH (nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net) that hosts several different sites (made in PHP). Currently no email is sent, which is quite problematic .. I have tried to configure everything, but so far nothing works.

I have a domain name with EuroDNS (nomdedomaine.fr), as well as email addresses at Google (gmail business, allowing for name@nomdedomaine.fr).

What I want as delivered: just that from the sites set up, you can send emails but not through the same shipping address. For example: I do not wish that on site1.com we receive emails from contact@nomdedomaine.Fr but rather contact@site1.com.

EuroDNS on, here is the DNS file:

```
; zone file for nomdedomaine.fr
$ORIGIN nomdedomaine.fr.
$TTL 3600

@    86400    IN SOA ns1.eurodns.com. hostmaster.eurodns.com. (
    2016050300 ; serial
    86400 ; refresh
    7200 ; retry
    604800 ; expire
    86400 ; minimum
)

@    86400    IN NS    ns1.eurodns.com.
@    86400    IN NS    ns2.eurodns.com.
@    86400    IN NS    ns3.eurodns.com.
@    86400    IN NS    ns4.eurodns.com.

; Mail Exchanger definition
@        IN MX    10 aspmx.l.google.com.
@        IN MX    20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
@        IN MX    20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
@        IN MX    30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
@        IN MX    30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.

; IPv4 Address definition
@               IN A    xxx.xxx.xx.xx
sousdomaine2    IN A    xxx.xxx.xx.xx
sousdomaine1    IN A    xxx.xxx.xx.xx
smtp            IN A    xxx.xxx.xx.xx
www             IN A    xxx.xxx.xx.xx

; Canonical Name definition
xxxxxxxxx        IN CNAME    gv-xxxxxxxxxx.dv.googlehosted.com.

; Sender Policy Framework definition
@        IN SPF    "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

On the OVH manager, the reverse IP is configured :

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xx   -   nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net.
```

On the OVH server:
I installed Postfix, configure php.ini with sendmail:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

/etc/hostname contain :

```
nsxxxxxxx.ovh
```

/etc/mailname contain :

```
nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net
```

/etc/hosts contain at the beginning of file :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
xxx.xxx.xx.xx           nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net       nsxxxxxxx.ovh
xxxx:xxxx:x:xxxx::      nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net       nsxxxxxxx.ovh
```

Postfix configuration with /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

#smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net<br>alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net, localhost.ovh.net, localhost<br>relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Finally, when I try to send an email via:

```
echo  "salut quelle note pour cet envoi de mail ?" | mail -s "tester mon envoi de mail" web-XtgXPY@yopmail.com
```

(YopMail can receive messages garbage, these are false addresses).

Obviously I have not received anything, and in the file mail.log the corresponding result:

```
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/pickup[19451]: 3CF87CC1F1: uid=0 from=<root>
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/cleanup[24287]: 3CF87CC1F1: message-id=<20160503120040.3CF87CC1F1@nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net>
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[12155]: 3CF87CC1F1: from=<root@#nomdedomaine.fr>, size=368, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/smtp[24289]: 3CF87CC1F1: to=<web-XtgXPY@yopmail.com>, relay=smtp.yopmail.com[87.98.164.155]:25, delay=0.19, delays=0.05/0/0.1/0.03, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host smtp.yopmail.com[87.98.164.155] said: 550 Unrouteable sender address (in reply to RCPT TO command))
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/cleanup[24287]: 641A3CC1F2: message-id=<20160503120040.641A3CC1F2@nsxxxxxxx.ovh.net>
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/bounce[24290]: 3CF87CC1F1: sender non-delivery notification: 641A3CC1F2
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[12155]: 641A3CC1F2: from=<>, size=2260, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx 018962 postfix/qmgr[12155]: 3CF87CC1F1: removed
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/error[24291]: 641A3CC1F2: to=<root@#nomdedomaine.fr>, relay=none, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
May  3 14:00:40 nsxxxxxxx postfix/qmgr[12155]: 641A3CC1F2: removed
```

I find myself a bit stuck .. I suspect the configuration is not correct but it is something too obscure for me .. Need a charitable soul :)

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure postfix` and choose the internet option.

Comment: I've 5 choices with 2 "internet" options :
No configuration, Internet site, Internet with smarthost, Satellite system, Local Only.

I must choose "Internet with smarthost" ?

Comment: "internet site" i think. By default it was on "local only" if you didnt reconfigure it.